# Named pipes in Python3.4, twisted and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pipe, twisted, named-pipes

**Context:**

My end goal is to make a scalable downloader. I chose the two scripts architecture because mongo doesn't work well with twisted, so I let one, non twisted script do the database read and write and another, twisted one, do the processing, taking in as much data as it is given by the first script.

I have a mongoDB database with a collection containing urls. Something like this:

```
record = {url:'www.somesite.com'} [PART OF SCRIPT 1]
```

I have a Python3 (3.4.2) script that connects to the database and feeds a number of records from the database to another Python3 script through a named pipe. Something like this:

```
named_pipe = os.open('pipe_name', os.O_WRONLY) [PART OF SCRIPT 1]
os.write(named_pipe, json.dumps(record)) [PART OF SCRIPT 1]
```

On the receiving script, I have a function, receive(), that is called by the twisted reactor. Something like this:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(receive) [PART OF SCRIPT 2]
```

The receive() function tries to download and save the urls source. So far so good. Although, I am uncertain about something. **This will be question 1**.

I receive my urls like this. **Question 2 will be related to these lines of code**:

```
named_pipe = open('pipe_name', 'r') [PART OF SCRIPT 2]
record = named_pipe.readline()[:-1] [PART OF SCRIPT 2]
```

Not all sources can be downloaded, so, upon encountering an exception, I want to send back, to the first script, a record that looks like this:

```
other_record = {'url':'www.somesite.com','downloaded':False} [PART OF SCRIPT 2]
```

or, if it is downloaded, a record like this:

```
other_record = {'url':'www.somesite.com','downloaded':True} [PART OF SCRIPT 2]
```

For this purpose, I made another named pipe:

```
other_named_pipe = os.open('other_pipe_name', os.O_WRONLY) [PART OF SCRIPT 2]
```

At this point, when I introduce the second named pipe, my script stops. The debugger shows the script stopping at this line (or the equivalent line in the first script, that is suppose to receive records through this pipe). **This will be question 3.** The equivalent line in the first script looks like this:

```
other_named_pipe = open('other_pipe_name', 'r') [PART OF SCRIPT 1]
response_from_script_2 = other_named_pipe.readline()[:-1] [PART OF SCRIPT 1]
```

So, my questions:

**Question 1:**

Does one pipe make sense in the context of twisted? Should I have more than one pipes feeding input to the second script in order to make better use of twisted's asynchronous model?

**Question 2:**

The script doesn't work if I change the first line of code to:

```
named_pipe = os.open('pipe_name', os.O_RDONLY)
```

or the second one to

```
record = named_pipe.readline()
```

Nothing is being sent anymore if I make the first change and if I make the second change, printing the line does not display anything and json no longer parses the string. Why does this happen?

**Question 3:**

3.1. Can I have multiple named pipes between two scripts?

3.2. Is communication through pipes efficient in the context of twisted?

3.3. What other ways are there to make two scrips communicate, especially between one that runs in twisteds reactor and another that doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you whole philosophy is wrong. Why you're using `os.open()`? Have you used `os.mkfifo()` prior to these? Do you have named pipes already created on the filesystem? If not they're just plain files. I'm not 100% sure, why your scripts stops on the write-only open, I would need to experiment a bit to confirm my theory. I think your pipe/fifo is blocked until another process starts reading from it.

If you already using Twisted, why you focus on such primitive IPC mechanism like fifos/pipes? There are much better message passing mechanisms, than these that even don't guarantee you'll receive youe message in one piece.

StackOverflow is full of answers about 'Twisted IPC', just Google a bit.

Comment: I think you are right about the pipe being blocked. I will check and confirm. What IPC would you recommend?

Comment: You were right, I solved this by making a listener thread and a sender thread.

Comment: I'm not Twisted guy, so from my experience I cannot advise anything related to it. I usually don't write multiprocess stuff in Python, mostly multi-threading, and then I use queues.